# Specifying path using PyQt5 QtFileDialog.getOpenFileName() using a variable rather than a literal string

Tags: python, pyqt

If I do the following:

```
self.file_dialog, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open a calendar event(s) file", "/home/mdavies/Desktop/",
                    "iCalendar Files (*.ics)")
```

the file dialog opens in correct folder (/home/mdavies/Desktop/).  However, if I try to use a variable instead of literal for the path:

```
from os.path import expanduser

folder = expanduser("~/Desktop")

self.file_dialog, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open a calendar event(s) file", folder,
                    "iCalendar Files (*.ics)")
```

I'm running the code on Kubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.5.2 and PyQt 5.5.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works, I find it very strange that you have problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a (in hindsight) obvious solution that means I don't have to use a variable:

```
self.file_dialog, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open a calendar event(s) file", expanduser("~/Desktop"),
                    "iCalendar Files (*.ics)")
```

Still unclear why variable didn't work though.